# Issue with soul and nested macros

Tags: macros, highlighting, soul

I'm using package `soul` to highlight text, for example with `\hl{some text}`.
It works nicely in general, but when the text contains other macros, `soul` simply skips it.
For example:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\removed}[1]{\st{#1}}
...
\removed{Some articles by \cite{someauthor2013} support this view.}
```

turns out in the pdf as `Some articles by`, cutting the macro and all the subsequent text. The same happens with `\st` and all the other highlighting macros.

Any fix to make the `removed` macro more robust, possibly without changing the input text?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**: 
The following code solves the problem nicely.

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\newcommand{\removed}[1]{\reduline{#1}}
...
\removed{This text by \cite{someauthor2013} will be rendered with a red line on it.}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of soul. Section 2.1 and 2.2. You should also not ignore the log-file: your code should give errors.

Comment: query - where does \textcolor come from - when I try a small example it fails - presumably it comes from another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

OK, It seems you are not using soul properly -- `\package{soul}` is clearly wrong. Make it `\usepackage{soul}`. Having said that the following code works. (This technique of adding `{}` may not work always. Refer to `soul` documentation sections 2.1 and 2.2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\removed}[1]{\st{#1}}


\begin{document}
\removed{Some articles by {\cite{Ferrero:1997}} support this view.}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Ferrero, 1997]{Ferrero:1997}
Fererro, X.Y., 1997. text of teh rest of the reference.

\bibitem[Doe, 1999]{Doe:1999}
Doe, J., 1999. another reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Earlier answer:

Enclose `\cite{someauthor2013}` inside an additional set of `{}` and for this case it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}


\begin{document}
\hl{Some articles by {\cite{Ferrero:1997}} and {\cite{Doe:1999}} support this view.}


\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Ferrero, 1997]{Ferrero:1997}
Fererro, X.Y., 1997. text of teh rest of the reference.

\bibitem[Doe, 1999]{Doe:1999}
Doe, J., 1999. another reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `ulem`, things look some what easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\removed}[1]{\sout{#1}}


\begin{document}
\removed{Some articles by \cite{Ferrero:1997} support this view.}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Ferrero, 1997]{Ferrero:1997}
Fererro, X.Y., 1997. text of teh rest of the reference.

\bibitem[Doe, 1999]{Doe:1999}
Doe, J., 1999. another reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wrap the macro with `{}`, I get black squares and not text :-/

Comment: @Mulone Where is your code that gives this behavior? Please post it to your question starting from `\begin{document}` and ending at `\end{document`.

Comment: Ok. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. It might be some issue with my natbib set up, which is quite complex. Any more robust alternative to soul to simply strikeout some text?

Comment: @Mulone I suggest the use of `ulem`. Check out the `ulem` part in the answer.

Comment: `ulem` seems nice, but has the nasty problem of changing the style of all `em` commands...

Comment: @Mulone That is why I added `[normalem]` as the option to `ulem` hence that is avoided.